# Using PNUnit for Testing

Tags: pnunit

I am trying to set testcase for mywebsite, I want to test multiple users at a time. I come to conclusion that it will be possible with PNUnit. But I know nothing about that, I have search on google but I found nothing.
I got one link [blog]: http://testingbot.com/support/getting-started/pnunit.html but not getting clue from this, is anyone knows about the PNUnit- how to start using PNUnit throughout the test execution. If possible please provide step by step procedure.

Your help is appreciated.
Thanks